# Change Value of Cell based on two conditions VBA Macro

Tags: excel, vba

Good afternoon,

I have a few items that are ordered by multiple stores which have the same PROD Number and I need to change the name of "STORE 1".

Essentially, I need the Macro to do this: If E:E equals to LIST and G:G equals to "Store 1". Change "Store 1" to "Store 7".

LIST:18703,18709,17669,17668,18708,32945,27042,27041,18704,32941,32944,32942,18702,18705,18462,18461,18391,27039,33632,33633,33635,27045

How can I go about this?

Screenshot

[image: 1]

This is what I tried before but it only changes for the PROD Number not the Store.

```
Sub ChangeStore()
Dim lr As Long
Dim rng As Range
'Changes Ship to Parent Customer from Kroger to Kroger DC
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each rng In Range("E3:E" & lr)
        If (rng = 18709) Or (rng = 18703) Or (rng = 18705) Or (rng = 27042) Or (rng = 27041) Or (rng = 32598) Or (rng = 17669) Or (rng = 17668) Or (rng = 18708) Or (rng = 18704) Or (rng = 32595) Or (rng = 32596) Or (rng = 32596) Or (rng = 32596) Or (rng = 32596) Or (rng = 32596) Or (rng = 32596) Or (rng = 32596) Or (rng = 32597) Or (rng = 32599) Or (rng = 18702) Or (rng = 18462) Or (rng = 18461) Or (rng = 27039) Or (rng = 27045) Or (rng = 32941) Or (rng = 32942) Or (rng = 32943) Or (rng = 32944) Or (rng = 32945) Then
            rng.Offset(, 2) = "Store 7"
        End If
    Next rng
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Sub ChangeStore()
    Dim lr As Long, ws As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range
    
    'reference a specific worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data") 'for example
    'Changes Ship to Parent Customer from Kroger to Kroger DC
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each c In Range("E3:E" & lr)
        
        Select Case c.Value
            'Tidier than a long list of or'ed tests
            Case 18709, 18703, 18705, 27042, 27041, 32598, 17669, _
                 17668, 18708, 18704, 32595, 32596, 32596 'etc etc
                With c.Offset(0, 2)
                    If .Value = "Store 1" Then .Value = "Store 7"
                End With
            Case Else
                'do nothing
        End Select
        
    Next c
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variant of code:

```
Sub ChangeStore()
Dim lr As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim list
list = Array(18709, 18703, 18705, 27042, 27041, 32598, 17669, _
          17668, 18708, 18704, 32595, 32596, 32596, 32596, 32596, _
          32596, 32596, 32596, 32597, 32599, 18702, 18462, 18461, _
          27039, 27045, 32941, 32942, 32943, 32944, 32945)
'Changes Ship to Parent Customer from Kroger to Kroger DC
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row   '1
    For Each rng In Range("E3:E" & lr)
        If IsNumeric(Application.Match(rng.Value, list, 0)) Then
            With rng.Offset(, 2)
                 If .Value = UCase("Store 1") Then .Value = UCase("Store 7")
            End With
        End If
    Next rng
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use autofilter to update data w/o looping
- Assumes the data table ( ListObject ) starts from Col A

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub UpdateStore()
    Dim oTab As ListObject, oSht As Worksheet
    Dim aList, visRng As Range
    Const COL_PROD_NUM = 5 ' Col E
    Const COL_CUST = 7 ' Col G
    Set oSht = Sheets("Sheet1") ' Update sheet name
    ' Update List as needed
    aList = Split("18703,18709,17669,17668,18708,32945,27042,27041," & _
        "18704,32941,32944,32942,18702,18705,18462,18461," & _
        "18391,27039,33632,33633,33635,27045", ",")
    Set oTab = oSht.ListObjects("Table1")  ' Update table name
    If oTab.AutoFilter.FilterMode Then oTab.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    oTab.Range.AutoFilter Field:=COL_PROD_NUM, Criteria1:=aList, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    oTab.Range.AutoFilter Field:=COL_CUST, Criteria1:="STORE 1"
    On Error Resume Next
    Set visRng = oTab.ListColumns(COL_CUST).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not visRng Is Nothing Then
        visRng.Value = "STORE 7"
    End If
    oTab.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
End Sub
```